# Generate binary strings that are at least in d hamming distance using ECC

Tags: python, algorithm, encoding, error-correction

I want to generate binary strings of length n=128 with the property that any pair of such strings are at least in d=10 hamming distance.

For this I am trying to use an Error Correcting Code (ECC) with minimum distance d=10. However, I cannot find any ecc that has code words of 128 bit length. If the code word length (n) and d are a little bit smaller/greater than 128 and 10, that still works for me.

Is there any ecc with this (similar) properties? Is there any python implementation of this?

Comment: A Reed-Muller code can have that size and a distance of 8 or 16, is that ok?

Comment: @harold yes, that is fine. Can you please elaborate on this? Is there any python implementation?

Comment: Is there any other code with higher rate?

Comment: For example a BCH code with n=127 (add a bit of padding) and k=92, I don't immediately have Python code for that

Answer (score 1):

Reed-Muller codes RM(3,7) have:

- a block size of 128 bits
- a minimum distance of 16
- a message size of 64 bits

First construct a basis like this:

```
def popcnt(x):
    return bin(x).count("1")

basis = []
by_ones = list(range(128))
by_ones.sort(key=popcnt)
for i in by_ones:
    count = popcnt(i)
    if count > 3:
        break
    if count <= 1:
        basis.append(((1 << 128) - 1) // ((1 << i) | 1))
    else:
        p = ((1 << 128) - 1)
        for b in [basis[k + 1] for k in range(7) if ((i >> k) & 1) != 0]:
            p = p & b
        basis.append(p)
```

Then you can use any linear combination of them, which are created by XORing subsets of rows of the basis, for example:

```
def encode(x, basis):
    # requires x < (1 << 64)
    r = 0
    for i in range(len(basis)):
        if ((x >> i) & 1) != 0:
            r = r ^ basis[i]
    return r
```

In some other implementation I found this was done by taking dot products with columns of the basis matrix and then reducing modulo 2. I don't know why they do that, it seems much easier to do it more directly by summing a subset of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the exact same thing. For me the naive approach worked very well! Simply generate random bit strings and check hamming distance between them, gradually building a list of strings that fulfills the requirement:

```
def random_binary_array(width):
    """Generate random binary array of specific width"""
    # You can enforce additional array level constraints here
    return np.random.randint(2, size=width)

def hamming2(s1, s2):
    """Calculate the Hamming distance between two bit arrays"""
    assert len(s1) == len(s2)
    # return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))  # Wikipedia solution
    return np.count_nonzero(s1 != s2)  # a faster solution


def generate_hamm_arrays(n_values, size, min_hamming_dist=5):
    """
    Generate a list of binary arrays ensuring minimal hamming distance between the arrays.
    """
    hamm_list = []
    while len(hamm_list) < size:
        test_candidate = random_binary_array(n_values)
        valid = True
        for word in hamm_list:
            if (word == test_candidate).all() or hamming2(word, test_candidate) <= min_hamming_dist:
                valid = False
                break
        if valid:
            hamm_list.append(test_candidate)
    return np.array(hamm_list)

print(generate_hamm_arrays(16, 10))
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]]
```

And it's not too slow as long as you don't want a very dense list of strings (a small number of bits in a string + large hamming distance). From your specifications (128 bit strings with hamming distance 10 it is no problem) we can generate a 1000 bit strings in under 0.2 seconds on a really weak cpu:

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit(lambda: generate_hamm_arrays(n_values=128, size=100, min_hamming_dist=10), number=10)

>> 0.19202665984630585
```

Hope this solution is sufficient for you too.

Answer (score 0):

My O(n*n!) solution (works in a reasonable time for N<14)

```
def hammingDistance(n1, n2):
    return bin(np.bitwise_xor(n1, n2)).count("1")

N = 10 # binary code of length N
D = 6  # with minimum distance D
M = 2**N  # number of unique codes in general
# construct hamming distance matrix
A = np.zeros((M, M), dtype=int)
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(i+1, M):
        A[i, j] = hammingDistance(i, j)
A += A.T

def recursivly_find_legit_numbers(nums, codes=set()):
    
    codes_to_probe = nums
    for num1 in nums:
        codes.add(num1)
        codes_to_probe = codes_to_probe - {num1}
        for num2 in nums - {num1}:
            if A[num1, num2] < D:
                "Distance isn't sufficient, remove this number from set"
                codes_to_probe = codes_to_probe - {num2}

        if len(codes_to_probe):
            recursivly_find_legit_numbers(codes_to_probe, codes)
            
        return codes

group_of_codes = {}
for i in tqdm(range(M)):
    satisfying_numbers = np.where(A[i] >= D)[0]
    satisfying_numbers = satisfying_numbers[satisfying_numbers > i]
    nums = set(satisfying_numbers)
    if len(nums) == 0:
        continue
    group_of_codes[i] = recursivly_find_legit_numbers(nums, set())
    group_of_codes[i].add(i)

largest_group = 0
for i, nums in group_of_codes.items():
    if len(nums) > largest_group:
        largest_group = len(nums)
        ind = i

print(f"largest group for N={N} and D={D}: {largest_group}")
print("Number of unique groups:", len(group_of_codes))
```

---

largest group for N=10 and D=6: 6 Number of unique groups: 992

---

```
# generate largest group of codes

[format(num, f"0{N}b") for num in group_of_codes[ind]]
```

---

['0110100001',
'0001000010',
'1100001100',
'1010010111',
'1111111010',
'0001111101']